# Simplexml_load_string Entity parser error Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found

Tags: php, xml

I receive this warning when I try to get data from a call, I've tried with some solution for the same topic in stackoverflow but it doesn't work.

`[2] simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 4: parser error : Start tag expected, '&lt;' not found
simplexml_load_string(): ^`

the php code is as follow

```
    $api = new MktApi();
    $arr = array();
    $xlm = $api->handleResponse($api->getBrands());
    print_r($xlm);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xlm);
```

and the print I have is like this

`SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Head] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [RequestId] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) [RequestAction] => GetBrands [ResponseType] => Brands [Timestamp] => 2017-05-04T16:29:44-0500 ) [Body] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Brands] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [Brand] => Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [BrandId] => 22912 [Name] => DC Comics [GlobalIdentifier] => 101020216193 ) [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [BrandId] => 23324 [Name] => MIOS [GlobalIdentifier] => 101020216475 ) [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [BrandId] => 32298 [Name] => 988 [GlobalIdentifier] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) ) [3] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [BrandId] => 30015 [Name] => About Time [GlobalIdentifier] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( ) )`

it's look like correct XML, I've tried to add the xml header but I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `$api->handleResponse(...)` returns a SimpleXMLElement object. You don't need to parse it again.

Comment: another question `Use of undefined constant PHP_QUERY_RFC3986 - assumed 'PHP_QUERY_RFC3986` my php code `$queryString = http_build_query($parameters, $numeric_prefix, $arg_separator, $enc_type = PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);` how could I fixe it?

Comment: @javaTodev Named parameters aren't a thing in PHP. Remove `$enc_type = ` from the method call.

Comment: I've tried like this `http_build_query($parameters, '', '&', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986);` but I still receive the same warning.

Comment: The constant `PHP_QUERY_RFC3986` does not exists.

Comment: Ah yes, it looks like it was added in PHP 5.4. Which PHP version are you using @javaToDev?

Comment: @Chris PHP 5.3.26 but it works for PHP 5.5.12 who use it in localhost without issue. will be the PHP version?